# Why does Rails 4 say Missing Helper file, though it is there?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, ruby-on-rails-4, missing-data

I wrote a project in Rails 3. There are three controllers, three views, three helper files (very small project).

One of the helper files, which probably is causing the problem:

```
> cat helpers/my_helper.rb

module MyHelper

    require 'some_gems'
    ...

    def my_function ()
       ... #some functionality
    end

end
```

Now I moved to Rails 4 (updated all the staff).

Still when just starting the app `rails s -b localhost -p 3000` and going to `localhost:3000` in browser I get an Exception:

```
AbstractController::Helpers::ClassMethods::MissingHelperError in WelcomeController#index
Missing helper file helpers/my_helper.rb
```

What is the problem? The file is there, why Rails still missing it?

Comment: the problem was in Gemfile :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the helper could not be loaded because of missing gems from which it is trying to require libraries. Please check that your `Gemfile` includes all gems that you need for this helper.

Comment: great! but it was not really noticeable.